# Spring Roo how to maintain state between commands

Tags: java, state, spring-roo

I have written a couple of simple addon's for Spring Roo. How do you maintain state between succesive commands?

Comment: See this answer to a similar question 
[maintain state with spring between requests][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856440/maintain-state-with-spring-between-requests

Comment: I agree, this first answer is probably the best bet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1856856/364485

Comment: I think JavaMark wants to carry state between consecutive Spring Roo shell commands, not between Spring web requests.