# ModelMap, Session attributes and Spring Portlet MVC

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, portlet

What's the real role of ModelMap in Spring Portlet MVC? I've been testing a few portlets using Spring Portlet MVC 3.0 in WebSphere Portal 7 and it seems **every** attribute set in ModelMap gets stored in PortletSession.

If that's the case, what's the role of Session Attributes? (by the way, there's a several bug including clearing these guys). And what if I want to store attributes that last only to the current request? (For example, a Confirmation Message). If I put this message in the ModelMap, it gets stored in session and I have to manually clear it every time a user gets into Portal.

Comment: By default, ModelMap is not bound to session. Maybe there is something else in the code that is putting ModelMap in session? Please see this link if it helps:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856440/maintain-state-with-spring-between-requests

Answer (score 0):

If you have added `@SessionAttributes` annotation to your controller class and have the same `@ModelAttribute` value, then there is a chance of storing your ModelMap to the PortletSession. But ideally, ModelMap is not defualtly store in PortletSession.